# Time difference between two Python datetime objects in fractional seconds

Tags: python, python-datetime, timedelta

I am looking for an easy/Pythonic way to get the elapsed time difference (in fractional seconds) between two Python datetime objects.

In the example below, I can see the delta.seconds and delta.microseconds attributes but am not sure what they actually contain and how they relate to the value returned by total_seconds().

I would like to have the elapsed time difference down to 1 decimal point if possible rather than rounded to whole seconds.

I know this is a simple question but even after googling I am unable to determine what delta.seconds and delta.microseconds actually contain when you construct a timeobject from the difference between two datetime objects (as below) rather than by a direct instantiation call.  Once I know this information, I should be able to proceed the rest of the way myself.

```
>>> mtime = datetime.strptime("2005-02-08T07:18:22", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
>>> ctime = datetime.strptime("2005-02-08T07:18:26Z",  "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
>>> delta = mtime - ctime
>>> delta.total_seconds()
-4.0
>>> delta.seconds
86396
>>> delta.microseconds
0
```

Thank you for answering this simple question,

Catherine

Comment: "I would like to have the elapsed time difference down to 1 decimal point if possible rather than rounded to whole seconds." It isn't rounded, that is exact. You already have your answer, `delta.total_seconds()`.

Answer (score 0):

total_seconds() is the entire delta time span expressed in seconds.

Not sure what seconds represents in this case, you subtracted a time farther in the future (ctime) from mtime.  Typically you would do the opposite.

microseconds makes sense, as neither of your time variables contained microseconds.

make a program that sets time.now to a var, sleeps for a short time and then does it again.  then subtract those values from each other and look at the result, then it will start to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `mtime` is `greater` than ctime.
Im not 100% sure why it is like this however it is

if you reverse them you will get

```
seconds = 4
microseconds = 0
```

so the easiest way to get the information accuratly would be

```py
detla = mtime - ctime if mtime > ctime else ctime - mtime
```

This will  ensure the delta is always a positive number which will aloow you to accuratly get subract the larger number from the smaller number

Comment: but why? `delta.total_seconds()` is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Ah now I see.

If I take care to calculate delta as <larger_time> - <smaller_time> then it works and makes perfect sense.  It was the negative timedelta that was fouling things up.  This is VERY useful to know !!

See below.

```
>>> mtime = datetime.strptime("2005-02-08T07:18:22.301000", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> datetime.strptime("2005-02-08T07:18:26Z",  "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
>>> delta2 = ctime - mtime
>>> delta2.seconds, delta2.microseconds
(3, 699000)
>>> delta2.seconds + delta2.microseconds/1000000
3.699
```

Comment: But *you don't need to do this*. You just want `delta2.total_seconds()`, nothing was being fouled up.

Answer (score 0):

So, negative time deltas can be a little confusing. But basically, time delta objects store three values: days, seconds, and microseconds. The `.total_seconds` method *could* be implemented thusly:

```
def total_seconds(delta):
    return (
        delta.days * 86400 
        + delta.seconds 
        + (1/1000000)*delta.microseconds 
    )
```

Note, `delta.total_seconds()` already returns this. This is is **not a rounded number**.

[Internally, these values are normalized according to the following constraints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

> `0 <= microseconds < 1000000`
>
> `0 <= seconds < 3600*24` (the number of seconds in one day)
>
> `-999999999 <= days <= 999999999`

Note, `3600*24 == 86400`

So, to represent *negative one second*, for example, it is normalized to:

```
microseconds == 0
seconds == 86400 - 1 == 86399
days == -1
```

For your time delta of negative four seconds (exactly), you have:

```
microseconds == 0
seconds == 86400 - 4 == 86396
days == -1
```

If you want a absolute difference, just use:

```
abs(delta.total_seconds())
```

And let the timedelta keep the directional difference information.

Comment: Yeah this makes much more sense now.  I wasn't considering the "days == -1" when looking at seconds and microseconds for my original example and was thus getting very confused.

I've definitely learned something today so thank you all.